# Sent two btc transacton to payeer wallet less than the mnmum deposit,neither where credited

Tags: transactions, confirmations

recently sent to my payeer wallet a 0.0002 btc transaction which is less than the 0.0005 minium btc deposit, then did a second transacton of 0.0003 btc thnking that it will sums up.

Both transaction where conrmed more than 100 times and sent to the payeer wallet adress but are not credited and payeer system refuse to credited it. Yet those btc habe been sent to as the bitc explorer show for a total deposit of 0.0006 btc?

What can  do to retrieve my funds ?

Answer (score 2):

> What can do to retrieve my funds ?

Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed once they have been included in a block that is part of the valid chain.

The only way is to have the funds returned is to contact the person you sent them to, and ask for them back.